# How do I automatically open for equally sized firefox windows with a certain URL?

Tags: windows-10, firefox

Is easy to get two equally sized windows of a software in Windows 10 however I haven't found a good way to create 4 windows when I want to see 4 websites I browse with Firefox at the same time.

Is there a good way to do this on Windows 10?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/fQQGGJR.png)?

Comment: @Codelt : Yes, I want to be able to go directly to such a view without sizing the individual windows manually each time.